# Webtorrent - how to stream from a predefined URL of a .torrent file

Tags: webtorrent

I'm just wondering if it is possible to stream from a predefined URL of a .torrent file?

Am I not clear? Let me clarify. Please see this- http://medhabi.com/torrent/

This is something I downloaded from the internet. As you see, it requires to upload a .torrent file and then streams the movie. But what I want is to preset a remote URL of a .torrent file. And I don't want any form to upload file.

Let's say, if a visitor opens this URL http://medhabi.com/torrent/, it'll start streaming from this .torrent file https://yts.ag/torrent/download/D066D4D0EBEFB95102BB44FECDEB5A5FD519E29F.torrent

How do I do that? I'm not good at JavaScript.

(I have added a JSFiddle link in the comment)

Comment: JSFiddle- https://jsfiddle.net/s7a1u86z/

Answer (score 0):

It won't work because most probably that torrent doesn't have nany WebRTC seeders (the ones that work in the browser)

Please don't use SO and WebTorrent for piracy.